# Related videos depending on title and description

Tags: php, mysql, youtube

I am working on a project where I need to show related videos of the currently selected video. I just want to know how can I get related videos(like in youtube) depending on video title and description. Please suggest a method using PHP/MySql.

Is levenshtein php function a good option ??

Comment: I'm not gonna code for you. Let us see your tries, let us know what you mean by "related" etc.

Comment: Related I mean the videos having similar to words in the title and descriptions.

Comment: save user clicks and store former-after relationships in a table with two or more appropriate columns. second videos are often relevant to the first ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Levenshtein Distance Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or its php function, or just `like` MySQL operator to get the matching data and there is also [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm), and if your data is in English and one word column you can use [Soundex Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).

You will find alot of implementations out there for these algorithms

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is to use full text search of MySQL. Create a full text index on title or even on title and description of your videos.

Then use search query like this: (not testing this code now, this is more of a general idea for your code)

```
$sth = $PDO->prepare('SELECT id, title from VIDEOS where MATCH (title) AGAINST (:subj)');
$sth->bindParam(':subj', $term, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$aRes = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Full text search returns pretty decent results, I mean it orders by better matches.